# Shift reduce conflicts in mid rule action bison

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, bison, bnf, shift-reduce-conflict

I have the following grammar that is giving me three shift reduce conflicts:

```
boolexpression:         boolexpression OR boolterm 
                        | boolterm ;

boolterm:              boolterm AND boolfact
                        | boolfact;

boolfact:               "!" "(" boolexpression ")"
                        | "(" boolexpression ")"
                        | BOOLLITERAL
                        | expression boolop expression

boolop:                 "<"| ">"| BOOLOPLEQ /* <= */ | BOOLOPGEQ /* >= */ | BOOLOPEQ /* == */ | BOOLOPNEQ /* != */; 

expression:             sum ;

sum:                    sum "+" term         
                        | sum "-" term      
                        | term ;

term:                 term "*" factor
                        | term "/" factor 
                        | factor;

factor:                 ID        
                        | NUMBER       
                        | "(" {/* rules to generate IR/*} expression ")";
```

When I remove `{/* rules to generate IR/*}`, everything works fine.

Comment: The grammar you've posted has no conflicts, so the conflicts you see are coming from some other part of the grammar that you've left out of your post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conflict is because you have a mid rule action immedietely after `"("` in the `factor` rule. In this case you can't do this because the reductions `boolfact --> "(" boolexpression ")"` and `factor --> "(" {/* rules to generate IR/*} expression ")"` both contain the `"("` token as their first token recognized. So when bison recognizes a `"("`, it doesn't know which rule to reduce to.

One solution is to place `{/* rules to generate IR/}` somehwere after `expression` in `"(" {/ rules to generate IR/*} expression ")";`. There is also more helpful information found at https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Conflicts.html#Mid_002dRule-Conflicts.